# How to add columns into multiple CSV files in a single directory without adding quotation marks?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have thousands of CSV files in a single directory. I'm looking for a way how to add 2 columns (including headers) to each file.

There are some conditions:

1. There is always 0 value in column #5
2. In column #6 I want to store file name without extension (ABC)

INPUT FILE EXAMPLE (FILENAME IS ABC.CSV)

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4
04/22/2012,47.64,47.97,47.05
04/23/2012,47.6,48.2,47.4
04/24/2012,48.13,48.33,47.84
04/25/2012,47.81,48.14,47.59
04/26/2012,47.83,48.21,47.49
04/27/2012,47.2,47.31,46.84
04/28/2012,47.01,47.05,46.33
```

The code I've posted below has 1 problem,

1. It adds  quotation marks ("04/22/2012","47.64","47.97","47.05","0","ABC") to every value in a new file.

OUTPUT FILE EXAMPLE I NEED

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5,HEADER6
04/22/2012,47.64,47.97,47.05,0,ABC
04/23/2012,47.6,48.2,47.4,0,ABC
04/24/2012,48.13,48.33,47.84,0,ABC
04/25/2012,47.81,48.14,47.59,0,ABC
04/26/2012,47.83,48.21,47.49,0,ABC    
04/27/2012,47.2,47.31,46.84,0,ABC
04/28/2012,47.01,47.05,46.33,0,ABC




$files = Get-ChildItem ".\" -filter "*.csv"

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
$outfile = $files[$i].FullName + "out" 
$csv = Import-Csv $files[$i].FullName 
$newcsv = @()
foreach ( $row in $csv ) {
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'HEADER 5' -Value '0'
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'HEADER 6' -Value   $files[$i].BaseName
    $newcsv += $row
}
$newcsv | Export-Csv $files[$i].FullName -NoTypeInformation
}
```

And one more question. Because I have thousands of files in a directory, is this code efficient enough to do a task as fast as possible?

Somebody has already suggested me to improve code by Instead of looping thru the rows consider building te members with select

```
$csv = $csv | select-object *,@{n="HEADER5";e={0}},@{n="HEADER6";e={$file.BaseName}}
```

But I don't know how to implement his suggestion into my code.

Comment: Yes it is powershell.

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: In average there is about 300 rows per file. And I have about 4000 files in a single directory.

Comment: Is that trailing comma in the second data row a typo, or does that actually appear in the data?

Comment: sorry it is a typo. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested:

```
$InputFolder = 'c:\SomeFolder'
$OutputFolder = 'c:\SomeOtherFolder'

Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.* |
where {-not $_.psiscontainer} |
foreach {
 $FileName = $_.Name
 $BaseName = $_.Basename
 $data = Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 0
 "$($data[0]),Header5,Header6" | Set-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
 $data[1..($data.Length -1)] -replace '$',",0,$BaseName" | 
  Add-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
}
```

Comment: There is an error."Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File' ". I would also need to write into same folder(rewrite those files, just to add 2 more columns).

Comment: What version are you running? Adjusted the answer for V2.

Comment: You can write them back to the same file by making $InputFolder and $OutputFolder the same.  I intentionally made it not overwrite the files in the example so you can test without destroying the original data if it goes sideways.

Comment: I'm not sure if I checked it right, but in my registry it says RuntimeVersion v2.0.50727. But there is no Powershell "2" folder in my registry just "1" so i think it is powershell 1. I also use ps1 extension for my script files.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works. Does it worth to upgrade to powershell V3 or V4? Would all my old scripts work under V3 or V4? Would those scripts run faster?

Comment: There were some definite performance enhancements made in V3 and V4.  There are a few instance where scripts need to be modified for the new versions, but they are few and far between.  It's definitely worth the upgrade, IMHO.  You also get a much nicer ISE.

Comment: Hi  mjolinor. I have a simple question to your code, but I'm not sure if there is a simple answer... How your code must be changed to place Header6 column with data($BaseName) BEFORE first column. Hopefully not a big change must be done because I really like how efficient and fast is your original code. Thanx

Comment: Start a new question on that.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Just asked.

Answer (score 1):

I think my original answer depended too much on v3/v4 stuff, how about something like the following:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem ".\" | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".csv" }

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $outfile = $files[$i].FullName + "out" 
    $csv = Import-Csv $files[$i].FullName 
    $newcsv = @()
    foreach ( $row in $csv ) {
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'HEADER5' -Value '0'
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'HEADER6' -Value   $files[$i].BaseName
        $newcsv += $row
    }

    ( $newcsv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation ) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace  '"', '' } | Out-File $outfile

}
```

Comment: There is an error too. "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method name 'Replace'.

Comment: There are no quotation marks in my original files. For some reason those marks are added after adding 2 new columns into my files.

Comment: The quotes are from the export-csv. (convertto-csv does it too).

Comment: I've tired to change your .Replace('"','') with Replace('"',"") but it didn't work either.

Comment: made an edit to remove some newer features your version of powershell might handle poorly, I hope... :)

Comment: Now it works OK. I have one more question. Does it worth to upgrade to powershell V3 or V4? Would all my old scripts work under V3 or V4? As I mentioned earlier I have around 4000 files in a directory, would the code run faster under PS4 or this code itself is close to maximum efficiency?

Comment: Somebody has already suggested me to improve code by Instead of looping thru the rows consider building te members with select      $csv = $csv | select-object *,@{n="HEADER5";e={0}},@{n="HEADER6";e={$file.BaseName}}